# WP_QUERY post_in problem

Tags: php, wp-query

why when i using this code :

```
$paramss = array('post_in' => array( 760, 761) , 'post_type' => 'product');
$wc_querya = new WP_Query($paramss);
```

i get 5 products list and not only product with id 760,761 ?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[As documented](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#post-page-parameters), it's `post__in`, with two underscores:

```
$paramss = array( 'post__in' => array( 760, 761 ) , 'post_type' => 'product' );
```